# Intermittent vb.net oracle connection problem

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle

I am seeing a strange intermittent connection failure. My application works just fine and then starts throwing connection failure exceptions. A reset of IIS is required before the app will start working again. I've been able to trace a few of the failures back to an unexpected restart of the oracle cluster but not all of them. Has anyone else seen this problem? I've searched the web but haven't found anything.

Client - Win2003 server, IIS running ASP.net 2.0.50727, code is VB.NET, ODBC connection via Oracle Client 10.2.0.1.0

Server - Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production on a Linux cluster.

Failure:

```
Attempting connection.Open()
FAILED connection.Open()
Message: 
Stack Trace: 
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src,     String procedure) 
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src) 
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open() 
at MABridge2._0.debug.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\xxxx\My Documents\Visual Studio     2008\Projects\xxx\debug.aspx.vb:line 19
Closed connection
```

Code:

```
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Partial Public Class debug
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim loggingstring As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim connString As New String("Data Source=xxx_rac;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxxx;")
    Using conn As New OracleConnection(connString)
        Dim cmd As New OracleCommand()
        Response.Write("Attempting connection.Open()" + "<br>")
        Try
            conn.Open()
        Catch ex As OracleException
            Response.Write("FAILED connection.Open()" + "<br>")
            loggingstring = "Message: " + ex.Message + "<br>" + "Stack Trace:" + ex.StackTrace + "<br>"
            Response.Write(loggingstring)
        End Try
        conn.Close()
        Response.Write("Closed connection" + "<br>")
    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: are any Oracle error messages and error codes available? currently I see a stacktrace but no Oracle error code/message.

Comment: No error message was returned. You see "Message: " + ex.Message but it returned nothing

Comment: I recently added automatic notified for when a failure occurs. I've seen three failures. They occur every 1 to 2 weeks. In two of three cases, all six clustered web servers were affected. In one case, two of six servers were unaffected. Occasionally, IIS also needs to be reset twice before the error goes away.

Comment: You should be using VB.NET "using" statement everywhere in your code to ensure you're not exhausting connections from the pool, especially in an environment that raises errors sometimes. See here: http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/fritz/archive/2005/04/28/7834.aspx. Can you check this and retry?

Comment: Today I ran a simple single threaded load test on one of the servers and count not induce a failure after 1000+ requests. I looked through the logs and the app doesn't get much volume. A few hundred requests over a week or two is all that it takes before the problem pops up. I'm still going to add the using statement but I don't think the code is running out of resources.

Comment: It would be helpful to capture the *full* exception. There's a lot more info available, eg., .Number should give you an Oracle error number, and .Errors should give you an OracleError object, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying your code to dispose of your OracleCommand instance, otherwise you will have a resource leak which could be the cause of your problems.

```
Dim connString As New String("Data Source=...")
Using conn As New OracleConnection(connString)
    Using cmd As New OracleCommand()
        Try
            conn.Open()
        Catch ex As OracleException
            logger.LogError(ex.ToString())
            Throw 
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Testing for understanding.. The purpose of the using command is to make sure that my oracle command object is disposed of correctly. But I still need to call conn.Close() explicitly?

Comment: The OracleConnection is disposed in the `using` block which will in turn close the connection. So no you don't need to call `close` explicitly. The opposite is not true however, calling `close` does not dispose the instance.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the problem:

- The error occurs on connection open
- the error occurs after the system has been used for a while
- The error is temporarilly solved by doing an IIS reset

Based on this it sounds as if your code is leaking connections or some other resource.

For performance counters and events see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B13831_01/monitor.htm#i1005706

Comment: Yes to your 3 bullet items. This test page is as simple as it gets but once the failure occurs I can't get past it without resetting IIS. I even took a server offline (load balanced environment) and the next day the error was still there. I'd think open connections would eventually close on their own. This is also the only VB.net application on the server that uses that datasource. I have another ASP (classic) app that runs on the server and seems to be unaffected. I can verify the next time it happens.

Comment: Try monitoring the number of open connections, and check the connection pooling configuration

Comment: Shiraz, where would I check the connection pooling configuration? I don't see any options in the ODBC DSN setup. How would I go about checking the number of open connections? Are you talking about from the app server to DB or the DB itself?

Comment: Try using the performance monitor on the app server, the installation of the oracle client may have added some counters

Comment: Good idea. Unfortionately .Net data provider for Oracle and .Net data provider for SQLServer show counters but will not let me add any (Add button is greyed out). I tried a dev server and it has the same problem. My googling has not provided a solution.

Comment: Are all counters greyed out or just those? If it is all, are you logged in with admin rights?

Comment: No, just Net data provider for Oracle and .Net data provider for SQLServer. I can other counters just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your connect string that you are connecting to a RAC DB consisting of more than 1 instance...

IF my assumption is true then there could be another explanation:

In a RAC configuration the Oracle listener you connect to returns information telling the client to which instance the client should connect... that means: you connect to listener A and listener A tells you to connect to instance B. This is part of what happens "behind the scenes" (in Oracle Client, not in your code).

When a listener communicates this information it doesn't tell you an IP addresse but a NAME (DNS...). IF your computer can't resolve that name you get exactly the behaviour you describe... connecting works sometimes and sometimes not... either put all hostnames relevant to all RAC nodes into the local hosts or (better) make them DNS-resolvable in your LAN...

Comment: The TNS entry I am using is below. Does it provide any clues? There are five hosts (removed for brevity). I am pretty sure they are all locally resolvable but I can check that
`rdw_rac=
          (description= 
        (address=(protocol=tcp)(host=host5.xxx.com)(port=1661))
        (load_balance=yes)
        (source_route=yes)
        (connect_data=
          (server=shared)
          (service_name=rdw)
          (failover_mode=
            (type=select)
            (method=basic)
            (retries=180)
            (delay=5)
          )
        )
      )`

Comment: a little: the host host5.xxx.com must bew resolvable via DNS, BUT this is NOT enough... you need to check on the Oracle server side: how many RAC/cluster nodes are there ? which names do they have ? and then check whether ALL names of ALL nodes are resolvable to IP addresses on the web servers...

Comment: There are five servers and I was able to ping them all for the web server. In addition, I used telnet to check connectivity for the particular port since there are firewalls in between the server.

Comment: did you ping them via the names configured on the DB server-side ?

Comment: I pinged them via the name in the TNS names files, host1.xxx.com through host5.xxx.com. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: no... pinging them is only than any help IF you use the names configured on the Oracle Servers to ping NOT the names from TNSnames...

Comment: As you can tell, I'm obviously not familiar with the oracle side of things. What question(s) exactly should I be asking the DBA? What are the FQDNs setup as for the five RAC members?

Comment: exactly - he should be able to tell the FDQNs setup on the RAC nodes for each RAC node...